# gerund-participle clause as adjunct and modifier

Tags: gerunds, participles

> **Having read the report**, Hyde breathed a sigh of relief.

I have some questions regarding the part in bold.

1. I know it takes the role of adjunct, but what is it called? A gerund-participle clause, or a perfect gerund-participle clause?
2. Is **Have** still an auxiliary for perfect aspect or is it simply used to show which action happens first?
3. is **Reading the report, Hyde breathed a sigh of relief.** grammatical?
4. If I want to paraphrase the adjunct to a modifier of the subject Hyde, which one is grammatical? I think a is ungrammatical but I don't know why.

> a. Hyde having read the report breathed a sigh of relief.
>
> b. Hyde reading the report breathed a sigh of relief.
>
> c. Hyde, reading the report, breathed a sigh of relief.

Answer (score 1):

> [*Having read the report*]*, Hyde breathed a sigh of relief.*

It is a gerund-participial clause in adjunct function. More specifically, it's an adjunct of implicated reason, since it gives a reason for the matrix situation.

You could if you wish call it a 'perfect gerund-participial clause', where "have" is the perfect auxiliary.

> [*Reading the report*], *Hyde breathed a sigh of relief.*

I'd say that this is grammatical. Here, the gerund-participial clause is a supplementary depictive adjunct giving descriptive information about "Hyde". Note that it is interpreted with progressive aspectuality: "Hyde was reading the report".

Comment: So the perfect aspect of **having read the report**, serves to remove the progressive aspectuality of **reading the report**, is that correct? I find it difficult to understand why non-finite clauses can have perfect aspect when functioning as adjuncts and complements, but cannot when functioning as post modifiers.

Comment: @Gestaltfilter That's not quite true. In, for example, "The amount [being earned by Kim] is surprising", the clause "being earned by Kim" post-modifies "amount" and it has progressive aspectuality", but not progressive aspect, since "being" is the passive auxiliary, not the progressive one.

Comment: So let me get this straight, **being earned by Kim** is passive and has a progressive aspectuality; **earned by Kim** in _The amount earned by Kim is surprising_ is also passive but has a perfect aspectuality. By adding **being** to **earned by Kim** we turned a past-participle  into a gerund-participle and removed its perfect aspectuality. But we cannot  change a gerund-participle in _Hyde reading the report_ to a past-participle or a gerund-participle that has perfect aspectuality, at least not when the gerund-participle is a post modifier. Is this correct?

Comment: or maybe my interpretation regarding the _perfect aspectuality_ is based on the verb **earn** and **read**, in _People walking to work everyday..._, it seems **walking to work everyday** demonstrates no progressive but a habitual aspectuality.